# How could I click any html element and it would just delete/remove itself with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

been working on a thing for fun. I was wondering how I could delete an HTML element if I just clicked it on any website or HTML file. No **jquery** or **other libraries**, just **vanilla JS**. If the question is hard to understand here's an example:
-Website loads
-I see a p tag or img tag or just any tag and I don't want to see it anymore so I just click it and it deletes.
-I'm now happy because of what I've done.

currentCode:

```
window.addEventListener("click", function(i) {
  //Code to remove something? idk... Not that good with js atm...
}, false);
```

Comment: Your question needs a lot more context. Where is this javascript supposed to be running ? Is it a browser userscript you plan to inject into other websites? or a browser extension perhaps ? If it's located on (one of) your own sites, then realise that it won't be able to access the DOM of other browsertabs. you may also want to add what the aim of the project actually is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
window.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  const target = e.target;
  target.remove();
}, false);
```

```html
<button>a</button>
<button>a1</button>
<p>paragraph...</p>
<h1>header...</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

What about setting the element's display to none?

```js
const foo = document.getElementById('foo');
const bar = document.getElementById('bar');

[foo, bar].forEach((el) => {
  el.addEventListener('click', () => el.style.display = 'none');
});
```

```html
<div id="foo" style="border: 1px solid black; height: 50px; margin-bottom: 20px;"></div>
<div id="bar" style="border: 1px solid red; height: 50px;"></div>
```

EDIT: This time without IDs (this is a good intro to [event bubbling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events)):

```js
// Look ma, no ids!
window.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
  event.target.style.display = 'none';
});
```

```html
<div id="foo" style="border: 1px solid black; height: 50px; margin-bottom: 20px;"></div>
<div id="bar" style="border: 1px solid red; height: 50px;"></div>
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this without the element id's?

Comment: edited, check out [this intro to events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events)

Answer (score 0):

Here are two ways to achieve the same effect:-

```
document.getElementById("myDIV").style.display = "none"; // hides element

document.getElementById("myDIV").remove(); // removes element from the DOM
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this without the id's?

Comment: Yes, you can use any type of selector with it.

Comment: For example:- `document.getElementsByTagName('input')`,  `document.querySelector('.className')`,  `document.getElementsByClassName('className')`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to delete something that you don't want to see with a click event, you can use the style attribute.

Here is the js script you can use :

```
<script>
    window.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
        e.target.style = "display: none;";
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this [Remove Element](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_node_remove)

Comment: I'm afraid link-only answers are frowned upon here. Copy-paste the relevant code and explain why you think that might help the questioner.